Modify Max CLL and Max FLL values in HEVC stream
Is it possible to modify/edit the Maximum Content Light Level and Maximum Frame-Average Light Level values directly in a HEVC stream?
When encoding with x265, these values are set by the max-cll command line option.
FFmpeg has the hevc_metadata bitstream filter that can edit some of the static metadata present in a HEVC stream, but it doesn't seem to have/expose the capability to modify the aforementioned items.
I'm also aware that it's possible to override these value when muxing the HEVC stream in a mkv container, but I'd rather modify them in the elementary stream directly!
Thanks in advance for your help.

Do you mean modifying the values without re-encoding? As far as I know... If it's not listed in the Bitstream Filters Documentation, then it is not supported.

Yes that is why I'm asking if there's another tool/way I could modify those value, doesn't need to be FFmpeg specific either.
